# HTML to JSP conversion issues

Tags: html, jsp

I want an HTML textbox value to be converted in a variable.
I have the following:

```
<input type="text" name="abc" value="0">
  <br>
    <%
      String contb = request.getParameter("abc");
      out.print("The result is: "+contb);
    %>
```

Why do I receive a "NULL" result?

Comment: I digited two more lines above. the JPS codes!... I don't undestand why they don't appear! The code was: <input type="text" name="abc" value="0"><br>

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
<%
    String contb = request.getParameter("abc");
    out.print("The result is: " + contb);
    %>
```

Note the spaces.
If you leave no space between the string, "+" operator and contb then JavaScript cannot parse it as an operation